# Performance difference between bulk insert query and loop over single entity insert query in repository pattern build over entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Is there any Performance difference between  bulk insert query and loop over single entity insert query over sql Database

```
   //bulk entities insert query

void Insert(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
```

and

```
foreach(entity in entities)
{
   // use single entity insert query

   void Insert(TEntity entity);
}
```

Comment: Instinctively, I would say that bulk insert at worst will not be any worse than looping, and will only ever be equal or better.

Comment: Since you're using Entity Framework, isn't it all going to be saved when you call `SaveChanges()` in both cases? Also, when you have an update to your question, edit the original question.

Comment: Why don't you try both and see for yourself?

Comment: What *does* the `Insert(IEnumerable)` *do*? Does it *really* use a BULK INSERT - note that this term already means something! - or an equivalent direct-insert; *or* does it *loop internally* and use the EF to *insert each item* (one at a time)? If it uses the same approach (i.e. EF managed object-graph), then it likely *doesn't matter* where the loop is and it is *not* a "bulk insert".

Answer (score 0):

Use InsertRange. Maybe the first is already using it, the second is not and will be slower when adding a lot of entities.

Comment: Could you explain what effect this has on performance, and possibly link to supporting evidence?